# CLLocation how to parse data into my apps label

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I am making an app to get GPS location using CLLocation manager. Because of the ios 6 change i am using :

```
-(void)locationManager *) didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Then i declared a delegate so i can receive location updates in my view controller and then pass them to my display label and i used this command inside didUpdateLocations :

```
[self.delegate locationsUpdate:[locations lastObject];
```

Considering that locations last object == new location that i used to use in the

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

But when i call my updatelocation in my viewcontroller like this :

```
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    locationLabel.text = [locations lastobject];
}
```

i get an error. In the previous version the command inside locationUpdate would have been :

```
  locationLabel.text = [location description];
```

Anyone has any idea of how to declare the command to get the last object of my array and display it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error ? `locationLabel.text = [location description];` isn't working ?

Comment: I was using the locationLabel.text = [locations lastobject];
 dont know why i did that :P Thanks for pointing out to use description. Thought it wouldn't work due to the different declaration i used in my class due to the function change of ios 6. Anyways thanks :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried

```
locationLabel.text = [location description];
```

Worked like a charm. Don't know why i didn't use that first. Thanks Templar for pointing out.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI: You called your delegate's method which waited for a CLLocation object, you gave the last location to it, but inside you didn't use the parameter `location` itself.